# How to inject the store into an Ember.Service in unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

In my app I have this initializer which injects the store into all services:

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
  application.inject('service', 'store', 'store:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'inject-store-in-services',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

My problem is that when I run unit tests, services don’t have the `store` property. So my question: is there a way to achieve what my initializer does but inside a unit test context?

Comment: Mock the store, a unit test shouldn't be going outside the scope of the service.

Comment: @Kingpin2k My service is actually just a wrapper around predefined operations on models that I don’t want to repeat everywhere in my app. I need to test that it returns a `DS.Model` with the correct properties set. Mocking the store would just test my mocks so...

Comment: It doesn't work when you run your tests.. Does it work when your app runs normally (not in test mode)?

Comment: It could be failing because your initialiser might be running before the store initialiser - which would mean it's not available yet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In recent versions of Ember you can inject the store as a service, e.g:

```
Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

It gets the service name from the property name, so if you call it something else you need to specify 'store'.. e.g:

```
Ember.Service.extend({
  banana: Ember.inject.service('store')
});
```

Comment: I knew the API for injecting services but I didn’t think it worked with the store. Thanks!

Comment: I think the store as a service was a recent addition.

Comment: For me, says "Attempting to inject an unknown injection: `service:store`".

Comment: It is documented, somewhere. Also, note that if you do this, you will have to say 'this.get('store')` instead of `this.store`.